# Increase space between parboxes

Tags: spacing, parbox

How do I increase the amount of white space in between two parboxes?
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\parbox[t][][t]{.5\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]} 
\parbox[t][][t]{.5\linewidth}{\lipsum[2]} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: a parbox has no spacing rules at all, it is just positioned like a letter, you have one word space like `X X` (so your line is overfull as you have paragraph indent, a .5\linewidth box, a word space, another .5\linewidth. so you can put any space between them that you would put between letters eg `\hfill` and then make them narrower so there is room between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: more space]

Note that this gives bad  box warnings because of the narrow columns and possibly the Latin.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\parbox[t][][t]{.475\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}\hfill
\parbox[t][][t]{.475\linewidth}{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```